# Gradient strokes in React Native ART

Tags: react-native

it seems that the original ART library doesn't support gradients on strokes because IE8 doesn't support it. But React Native doesn't have this limitation so gradient strokes would be lovely.
Any suggestions for how I might get the same effect anyway? I need a curved gradient.

Comment: the art module serve a LinearGradient creater,different from canvas you can't use it as the stroke color.To sum up,you can't do this till now.

Answer (score 0):

Check out https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-art-svg. It supports RadialGradient. https://github.com/magicismight/react-native-art-svg/blob/master/elements/RadialGradient.js

Comment: Unfortunately that won't solve it, since the gradient needs to change with angle, not with radius. One solution would a be a SweepGradient.